# Xubuntu - how to restore "default" terminal text coloring

Tags: command-line, xubuntu, colors

TerminalEmulator is preset to match Xubuntu theme, but it is rather low contrast and I would like to use other theme.

[image]

The standard ones, like Tango and Linux Colors are enough, any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

```
cp /etc/xdg/xdg-xubuntu/xfce4/terminal/terminalrc ~/.config/xfce4/terminal/
```

Comment: Cold you explain exactly what is going on?

Answer (score 4):

I guess digging a bit more did the trick:

https://github.com/sgerrand/xfce4-terminal-colors-solarized

**~/.config/Terminal/terminalrc** is responsible for the color settings that can be easily customised.

Comment: Xubuntu 13.04 doesn't have `~/.config/Terminal/` directory

Comment: @M_1 In addition to that, I found a terminalrc offering the Tango Color Scheme that you mentioned in your original question here: http://blogs.n1zyy.com/andrew/2009/02/02/tango-color-scheme-for-xfce-terminal/

Comment: @Green perhaps it is under ~/.config/xcfe4/terminal/ in that version. Try modifying your terminal preferences (e.g. change the font). In one of the two directories, a terminalrc file should be present reflecting your changes.

Answer (score 3):

In 14.04 terminalrc was moved to /xfce4/terminal. Execute `rm ~/.config/xfce4/terminal/terminalrc` and restart terminal. All terminal settings (text, colors) will be reset to default

Comment: Deleting `~/.config/xfce4/terminal/terminalrc` doesn't restore terminal setting to default. I can't verify it now because I've upgraded my OS to 16.04. At least it doesn't in 16.04 and it probably doesn't in 14.04 too, if memory serves me right. You need to paste `/etc/xdg/xdg-xubuntu/xfce4/terminal/terminalrc` to `~/.config/xfce4/terminal/`.