# What is the "default" font for xubuntu terminals?

Tags: xubuntu, fonts

Running xubuntu 14.04; and today I had to increase the font size for a presentation ... and when toggling back I happened to click in the wrong place; and now I am struggling how to undo that.

So, basically I have two question:

1. Not so important: what is the default font used by the xubuntu "Terminal emulator"?
2. Is there a simple way to reset this settings (and maybe others) back to the "factory defaults"? Meaning: in eclipse, in most "appearance" configuration windows, there is a "reset" button that will undo all changes made by users. Does such a thing exist for xubuntu?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/508921/295286

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, with some help, I am able to answer my own question:

1. The default font is "DejaVu Sans Mono Book 9"
2. "factory defaults" can be restored by removing the corresponding config file: `rm ~/.config/xfce4/terminal/terminalrc`